# Expanding matrix powers

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, tensors

I am new to mathematica, so forgive me if I'm being stupid. :p

I have the following notebook:

[image]

I have two questions about it.

1. Why do the x's expand to `x**x**x**` etc.? I read that `**` indicates the non-commutative product. I added in the assumptions that `x > 0`, isn't that enough to indicate that it is a scalar?
   **EDIT:** Solved: changing `x > 0` to `x \[Element] Reals` fixed this.
2. Why does ExpandAll not expand the matrix powers? Is there any other way to expand these matrix powers?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

As this thread is getting a little obfuscated, I decided to post a new, clearer, question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157908/expanding-tensors).

Comment: I didn't use ** myself right? Mathematica did that :p

Comment: Which version are you using? On 10.2 it does not result in `**`.

Comment: I use version 11.1 :)

Comment: Ah, if I change x > 0 to x \[Element] Reals, the ** problem seems to be resolved. :)

Comment: As this question is getting a little obfuscated, I posted a new one with a clearer question.

Comment: It would be very helpful to have the actual code involved. An image (one too small for my eyes at that) is just not a viable way for someone reading this to replicate the issue.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, apologies. In the thread linked, I provided some code ready to be copy pasted.