# Expanding tensors

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, tensors

This is a follow-up on / clarification of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157899/expanding-matrix-powers) thread.

I have the following in a notebook:

[image]

```
$Assumptions = A ∈ Matrices[{3,3},Reals] && B ∈ Matrices[{3,3},Reals]
TensorExpand[(A+B).(A+B)]

(* MatrixPower[A + B, 2] *)
```

Apparently, [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand.html) does not expand the dot product if the two arguments of the dot product are equal. Is there any way I can expand these kinds of dot products of tensors in Mathematica, i.e. to get `A.A + A.B + B.A + B.B` in the above example?

Comment: Please always post copyable code, not just screenshots.

Comment: You could try `Distribute`.

Comment: Please add code examples as text instead of images. That makes it much easier for others to try your example and help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if MatrixPower works out of the box with Tensors. You could try building your own version, where you can build `Dot` in terms of `TensorProduct` and `TensorContract` as shown [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html) in section Properties&Relations (search for: "TensorProduct, in combination with TensorContract, can be used to implement Dot:")

Comment: Added the copyable code. :)

Comment: `Distribute` works like a charm! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific case, [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html) will work.

```
Distribute[(A + B).(A + B)]
(* A.A + A.B + B.A + B.B *)

TensorExpand[%]
(* A.B + B.A + MatrixPower[A, 2] + MatrixPower[B, 2] *)
```

Keep in mind that `Distribute` is a purely structural operation without any mathematical smarts.