# Expand tensor expressions with matrix powers and outer products

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, tensors

I would like to have `TensorExpand` distribute across repeated matrices involving outer products. [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157908/expanding-tensors) notes that `TensorExpand` has a problem with expressions of a matrix raised to a power greater than one:

```
$Assumptions =   u \[Element] Vectors[m, Reals] && 
    A \[Element] Matrices[{m, m}, Reals] && 
    B \[Element] Matrices[{m, m}, Reals];
TensorExpand[u . (A) . (A) .u ]
```

yields an expression involving `MatrixProduct`, `u.MatrixPower[A, 2].u`, whereas

```
TensorExpand[u . (A) . (B) .u ]
```

simply yields `u.A.B.u`. The [solution proposed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157910/83090) by @Szabolcs is to use `Distribute`:

```
Distribute[u . (A) . (A) .u ]
```

yields `u.A.A.u`. However, this doesn't work if the matrices in the quadratic form involve outer products:

```
Idm = IdentityMatrix[m];
Distribute[ u . (Idm + u\[TensorProduct]u) . (Idm + u\[TensorProduct]u) .u ]
```

yields `u.u + 2 (u.u)^2 + u.MatrixPower[u\[TensorProduct]u, 2].u` and just plain `Distribute` doesn't simplify the outer products. How can I avoid this behavior? I.e, have the above evaluate to `u.u + 2 (u.u)^2 + (u.u)^3`?

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) objects ["FromTensor"](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/FromTensor) and ["ToTensor"](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/ToTensor):

```
Idm=IdentityMatrix[m];
t = u . (Idm+u\[TensorProduct]u) . (Idm+u\[TensorProduct]u) . u;

$Assumptions = u ∈ Vectors[{m}];

TensorReduce @ ResourceFunction["FromTensor"] @ ResourceFunction["ToTensor"] @ t
```

> u . u + 2 (u . u)^2 + (u . u)^3

Comment: Is there a reason this would be preferable to something like `Distribute[ u . (Idm +\[TensorProduct]u) . (Idm * c + u\[TensorProduct]u) .u ] /. c->1`, which is the hacky solution I ended up using? I.e., making the repeated elements different by introducing a scalar and later getting rid of it? I don't have a good sense of what is and isn't a kludgy solution in Mathematica since algorithms for symbolic math tend to involve a bunch of heuristics / ad hoc tricks...